# How can i get a parse with Gson? I try to do it but i get an Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

It's my Main.class. I want to get a parse from Url. It contains a Json.

```
fun main (args: Array<String>) {
    val response = URL("https://api.looksites.tk/").readText()
    var gson = Gson()

    val data = gson.fromJson(response, Array<Response>::class.java)
    for (x in 0 until data.size) {
        print(data[x])
    }
}
```

It's my POJO

```
data class Response(
    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    val status: String? = null
)
```

It's my responce. I need to parse it.

```
{"status":"success","code":"200","message":"Access granted"}
```

It's my mistake. **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT**

Please, help me.

Comment: What is the raw text from the response?

Comment: its 
{"status":"success","code":"200","message":"Access granted"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line you're telling Gson that you're expecting response to be an array

```
val data = gson.fromJson(response, Array<Response>::class.java)
```

but based on your error message and what you've posted as the response in the comments, you're actually getting back a json object, not an array. If you change your code to

```
val data = gson.fromJson(response, Response::class.java)
```

It should correctly get your object